# Attributes of complex numbers in Weka

Tags: weka

I created a dataset includes complex numbers (samples of complex signals). The dataset has 80 instances and 1024 attributes, and I need to classify these signals into two classes via Weka. However, the Weka does not deal with complex numbers.
I am just wondering how this can be done?
I tried to change each complex sample into amplitude part {sqrt((real^2)+(imag^2)) and phase {arctan(imag/real)}, but I am confused how to link each amplitude with its corresponding phase when I create the arff file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weka has no notion of imaginary numbers, just real-valued ones. You will have to treat the imaginary/real part (or amplitude/phase) as separate attributes. And hope that algorithms will learn a relationship between them.

Of course, you can always engineer additional features to help the learning process, e.g., in which quadrant these such a number is located.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  In my case, I have a raw data. So, what I did is making the first attribute as  the amplitude value and the next attribute to be the phase, and I kept repeating until the end of the signal.